# Calculator in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have try to do a calculator in angular js

i have created button

```
 <li ng-repeat="number in numbers">
  <button  ng-click=calc(number)>{{number}}</button>
</li>
```

and operators

```
   <li ng-repeat="operator in operators">
      <button  ng-click=operat(operator)>{{operator}</button>
   </li>
```

controller

```
app.controller('myControl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
  $scope.operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
  $scope.calc = function(valueNum) {
    $scope.valore =valueNum;
  };
  $scope.operat = function(valueOper){
   $scope.operatore = valueOper;
   };
```

now how can i do for the operation  on html page ?

for example i press 3 then + and 3 
what I must declare on html?

i try with this but not run

```
<p> result {{value}} {{operator}} {{value}} </p>
```

thanks.

Comment: I think you should study the basic programming concepts like data types, operators, etc. before trying to implement an application.

Comment: What do `calc` and `operat` do?

Comment: Show us the `calc` and `operat` methods

Comment: i have edit the question, I have try to show on page the value and i see for example <p> number = {{valore}} </p>

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do :) but here, if you want to display the values you need to display <p> result {{valore}} {{operatore}} {{valore}} </p>. Although, I don't think you're doing it the right way - I'd say you better display a string, with a concatened value that you just clicked.

Comment: plunker with starter code with $eval solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/DGRqPi2aumcMuTXSAzdP?p=preview

Comment: thanks andriy but  i don't understand this part     var key = $scope.operator ? 'rightValue' : 'leftValue';
    $scope[key] = $scope[key].split('');
    $scope[key].push(val);
    $scope[key] = $scope[key].join('');

Comment: the logic is, while we did not enter any operator, I assume we are still entering left side number - like 1, 5, 7 will create 157. When operator is entered, I assume that we are at the right side (like 157 + 3). In order to chain numbers (like 1, 5, 7 will create 157), I first split current value (for example ('15').split('') will give an array [1, 5]), second I add the new numer to the end of this array (([1, 5]).push(7) will give [1, 5, 7]). Lastly I convert this array to a string: ([1, 5, 7]).join('') will give '157'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $eval can evaluate value of expression

Following is demo to resolve your issue

In HTML

```
<p> result {{$eval(expression)}} </p>
```

In Controller

```
        $scope.value1 = "1";
        $scope.operator = "*";
        $scope.value2 = "7"
        $scope.expression = $scope.value1 + $scope.operator + $scope.value2;
```